# JAWS accessiblity software with .Net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, jaws-screen-reader

I have a XAML form on a desktop application running .net 4.5 that dynamically changes the forms displayed on the window based on the selected comboBox.

My issue is that JAWS accessiblity software is reading the my combobox name incorrectly. Instead of reading the correct label for the field it's reading a hidden label.

Is there a .Net accessibility class that will help for screen readers or is there a XAML .Net attribute similar to the ["aria-hidden"](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden)? Which hides fields from screen readers, which I could do dynamically.

Comment: Is this occurring WITH already having set the [AutomationProperties.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt244345.aspx) on the parent already?

Comment: we don't have AutomationProperties.Name set at all.

Comment: How is AutomationProperties.Name related to accessibility?

Comment: Start there, if I remember right, JAWS adopted UI automation years ago, so it should become the default identified descriptor of the object and any children. You might browse the link a bit.

Comment: You'll see broham. Though for your particular issue, it may be `AutomationProperties.LabeledBy` you're looking for instead of `~.Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as we hashed out in the comments, JAWS adopted full UI Automation support years ago which provides folks on the dev end multiple quick/easy ways to get around some of the Accessibility hurdles.

For your instance it's all about [AutomationProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt244345.aspx) to instruct the reader what it actually cares about. Kind of an adhoc equivalent to `aria` stuff you're probably familiar with from the HTML world.

In any event, `AutomationProperties.LabeledBy` (or in other scenarios `AutomationProperties.Name`) give you a quick way to define the readers only respected string context to define an object or a section with a description it will apply only to that object, or to that object/panel and it's children as the source of truth as far as the reader is concerned.

Hope this helps, I mean who doesn't love being a hero? heh, cheers!